# Modern chain of responsibility design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++20

Based on this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188898/c-parsing-with-chain-of-responsibility/283409#283409), I tried to simplify the use case with simpler model,

Let me know if you have other suggests on optimizations potentially algorithmic.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
class AtmHandler
{
    static inline auto chain = std::make_tuple(
        [](auto &amt)
        {
            if (amt % 50 == 0)
            {
                std::cout << "Number of 50 Dollar:" << amt / 50 << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Request is completed so no need to forward it" << std::endl;
                return true;
            }
            int numberOf50Dollar = amt / 50;
            std::cout << "Number of 50 Dollar:" << numberOf50Dollar << std::endl;
            amt %= 50;
            return !amt;
        },
        [](auto &amt)
        {
            if (amt % 20 == 0)
            {
                std::cout << "Number of 20 Dollar:" << amt / 20 << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Request is completed so no need to forward it" << std::endl;
                return true;
            }
            int numberOf20Dollar = amt / 20;
            std::cout << "Number of 20 Dollar:" << numberOf20Dollar << std::endl;
            amt %= 20;
            return !amt;
        },
        [](auto &amt)
        {
            if (amt % 10 == 0)
            {
                std::cout << "Number of 10 Dollar:" << amt / 10 << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Request is completed so no need to forward it" << std::endl;
                return true;
            }
            std::cout << "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Can Not with draw this amout please enter correct amount" << std::endl;
            return false;
        });

public:
    bool parse(int value)
    {
        bool result;
        auto handle = [&](auto &h)
        {
            return result = h(value);
        };
        std::apply([&](auto &&...xs)
                   { (handle(xs) || ...); },
                   chain);
        return result;
    }
};
int main()
{
    AtmHandler handler;
    std::cout << handler.parse(530) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use the chain of responsibility for converting an amount of money into a number of bills, there are much better ways to solve that problem. But let's forget that for now. There are still some other improvements possible:

## Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`

[Prefer to use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n); the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually unnecessary and might impact performance.

## Avoid code duplication

You already duplicated a lot of code by using the chain-of-responsibility pattern for this problem, as the three handlers look very much alike. However, even within one handler you have duplication. Here's one way to address all that duplication:

```
template<std::size_t Denomination>
static inline auto billHandler = [](auto &amount) {
    std::size_t numberOfBills = amount / Denomination;
    std::cout << "Number of " << Denomination << " Dollar bills: "
              << numberOfBills << '\n';
    amount -= numberOfBills * Denomination;
    if (!amount) {
         std::cout << "Request is completed so no need to forward it.\n"
    }
    return !amount;
};

static inline auto chain = std::make_tuple(
    billHandler<50>,
    billHandler<20>,
    billHandler<10>,
    [](auto &amount) {
       std::cout << "Cannot handle the change!\n";
       return false;
    }
);
```

## Simplify `parse()`

Your `parse()` function is unnecessarily complex. There is no need for the lambda `handle`, and since `std::apply()` will return the return value of the function it calls, you can use that to directly generate the return value of `parse()`:

```
bool parse(auto value)
{
    return std::apply([&](const auto&... handler) {
        return (handler(value) || ...);
    }, chain);
}
```

## There is no need to make a `class`

If there is only one member function, and no state is stored in an object of `class AtmHandler`, the `class` is unnecessary. Instead, you could write a free function `parse()`.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent feedback, 
If it is a more complicated scenario, How about having the chain as static data member?

Comment: That's what you did in your code. There is nothing wrong with that if you are going to have a `class` anyway. But if you don't have any non-static data members, you don't need the `class`. Then just keep the chain in a `static` variable, or alternatively you could put it into a `namespace` to avoid polluting the global namespace.

Comment: Makes senese, TIL,